# change jquery.cookie.js to create cookie across domain (/)

Tags: javascript, html

i am setting this fancybox to open once per session using a session cookie. i am trying to set it site-wide, because at the the moment if i open a directory first (e.g. /about) it will set one for just that directory not the whole site:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var check_cookie = $.cookie('disclaimer-initial');
    if(check_cookie == null){
     $("#disclaimer-initial").fancybox({
        'titlePosition'     : 'inside',
        'transitionIn'      : 'none',
        'transitionOut'     : 'none',//added comma
        'onComplete'        : function() {
     $.cookie('disclaimer-initial', '1'); //removed '
        }
      });
     $("#disclaimer-initial").trigger('click');
  }
});
</script>
```

here's my jquery.cookie.js:

```
/*!
 * jQuery Cookie Plugin
 * https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie
 *
 * Copyright 2011, Klaus Hartl
 * Dual licensed under the MIT or GPL Version 2 licenses.
 * http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
 * http://www.opensource.org/licenses/GPL-2.0
 */
(function($) {
    $.cookie = function(key, value, options) {

        // key and at least value given, set cookie...
        if (arguments.length > 1 && (!/Object/.test(Object.prototype.toString.call(value)) || value === null || value === undefined)) {
            options = $.extend({}, options);

            if (value === null || value === undefined) {
                options.expires = -1;
            }

            if (typeof options.expires === 'number') {
                var days = options.expires, t = options.expires = new Date();
                t.setDate(t.getDate() + days);
            }

            value = String(value);

            return (document.cookie = [
                encodeURIComponent(key), '=', options.raw ? value : encodeURIComponent(value),
                options.expires ? '; expires=' + options.expires.toUTCString() : '', // use expires attribute, max-age is not supported by IE
                options.path    ? '; path=' + options.path : '',
                options.domain  ? '; domain=' + options.domain : '',
                options.secure  ? '; secure' : ''
            ].join(''));
        }

        // key and possibly options given, get cookie...
        options = value || {};
        var decode = options.raw ? function(s) { return s; } : decodeURIComponent;

        var pairs = document.cookie.split('; ');
        for (var i = 0, pair; pair = pairs[i] && pairs[i].split('='); i++) {
            if (decode(pair[0]) === key) return decode(pair[1] || ''); // IE saves cookies with empty string as "c; ", e.g. without "=" as opposed to EOMB, thus pair[1] may be undefined
        }
        return null;
    };
})(jQuery);
```

i know i need to set the path to "/" but i don't how to or where to do this. thanks in advance

Comment: my guess is that you'll just set `options.path` to `'/'` or `''`. But you should check their documentation for that option.

Comment: tried that. didn't work.

Comment: solved it.  nothing to do jquery.cookie.js

Comment: used  $.cookie('disclaimer-initial', '1',  { path: '/' }); //removed '

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$.cookie('disclaimer-initial', '1', { path: '/' });
```